# Call Eclipse Launcher with parameter

Tags: eclipse, launcher, processbuilder

I want to call eclipse launghcer with "-application" parmater like bottom. 
doCmd(command) function executes the command using processbuilder.

```
List<String> command = Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher"), "-application",    "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director", "-noSplash", "-uninstallIU",     "org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group");doCmd(command);
```

but `System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher")` returns:

```
"C:\Users\jiyoun.kim\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.2\eclipse.exe".
```

And physically, eclipse.exe does not exist in that path.
So, processbuilder does not work.

For executing eclipse launcher, what should I do?

Comment: @NotACleverMan you approved an invalid edit that put part of the question text as code and then you edited the code to be something else. Please pay attention.

Comment: Actually I changed the code BACK to what the author pasted in. The new formatting was ok (and more readable) but the code should not be edited to be something that the original author didn't write. You just changed the original author's code again.

Comment: @NotACleverMan no, the `<string>` was there, just hidden since it was interpreted as html when not marked as code.

Comment: You're right. My sincerest apologies. I will look out for that in the future.

Comment: What happens if you dump system properties on startup, are all paths wrong? Usually the eclipse launcher should preserve it's own path correctly, but maybe it is work dir?

Comment: System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher") should return eclipse installed path(C:\JAVA\Eclipse\Eclipse.exe), But, When I use "org.slf4j.Logger" for logging, it returns "C:\Users\jiyoun.kim\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.2\eclipse.exe". And, If I don't use Logger, it returns NULL. I don't understand why.. :(